# Vb.Net WebBrowser click (tablo inside) button

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I want to click that button. But I don't find code.

```
<li class="rtbItem rtbBtn"><a class="rtbWrap" href="#">
<span class="rtbOut"><span class="rtbMid"><span class="rtbIn">
<img alt="" src="icons/Export.png" class="rtbIcon">
<span class="rtbText">Export</span></span></span></span></a></li>
```

this is cc code.

[this is web site picture and button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpwz0.jpg)

Comment: `InnerText`. You could also filter the Elements, using the Attribute `className` and test for `rtbText`: `If [Element].GetAttribute("className").Contains("rtbText") Then ' Get the InnerText of the Element End If`. But, maybe do you want to invoke `click` on the Anchor with `class="rtbWrap"` instead?.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
        If elem.GetAttribute("className").Contains("rtbText") Then 'Get the InnerText of the Element End If
            MsgBox(elem.OuterText)
        End If
 Next
```

I tried this one. And not read I asked code. This code inside a tablo from website. Sorry bad eng. [This is web site and button picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkNL0.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to click on the `<span>` element? It doesn't look like it has an attached event. Btw, this is not an answer. You should update your question, showing this code, instead.

Comment: I don't know. I new here. I new write code. How can I click attach event button?

Comment: What button? You're not showing a button anywhere. You should post the address of the HTML page you want to automate (or a more complete subset of it) and a better description of what you're trying to achieve, otherwise is quite difficult to understand what you're trying to do.